# Get matching route from URL in rails (again)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get hold of the matching route for a url in rails? Given a url, I want to query the respective controller and action. Note, the current page isn't the url in question.

This question has been posed before but wasn't answered.

Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path( '/your/url/here', :method => :get )
```

:method can have :get, :post, :put and :delete

Comment: According to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2656, `#recognize_path` should be used only for functional testing (it ignores domain related information)